# VScode add some color to ramdom lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm very new to VSCode, and the experience has been annoying for one thing: it adds random colors to some blocks of the code. I have not figured out why: there is no block of instructions (like between { and }) or errors, or anything I could make sense of.

I just want them to disappear. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: disable all extensions and see if that solves the problem, then find which one is the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the `configuration editing` or other extensions cause this issue in VS by :

```
Open your Extensions.
- On the top right, click the three dots forming a horizontal line.
- Input "@builtin" in the search box.
```